# Writing content from a php file into another generated file

Tags: php, file

so i am trying to figure out how i can basiclly ' copy & paste' file from a already existing file to a new generated file.

Here is an example so it is more clear.

I am generating a page via user input

```
echo "New Page Name:" ;

$input = trim((fgets(STDIN, 1024)));
$path = __DIR__ . '\pages';

//Checks if user has made an input
if (!empty($input)) {
    //Checks if pages exists
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        FileManager::writeInFile($path, $input);
    }else {
        //If not it makes a new directory
        mkdir($path, 0777);
        FileManager::writeInFile($path, $input);
    }
}
```

Which works for now, here comes the tricky part where i cant really wrap my head around.

I have a file called stage.php in the module directory.
Which just contains this plain text

> Test from stage.php

If we look into my `writeInFile` Function

```
public static function writeInFile($path, $input){
    $fp = fopen($path . '/' . $input . '.php', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, 123);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

It now sucsesfully writes 123

into the file, which is all well.

What i'm trying to achive is to replace

> 123

with the text from the stage.php file which would be

> Test from stage.php

EDIT:

This is what i have tried so far, `$contact` returns a false bool.

```
public function getModuleContent() {
        $stage =  __DIR__ . '../module/stage.php';
        var_dump($stage);
        $content = file_get_contents($stage);
}
```

Here is the `var_dump` from `$stage`

```
string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\util../module/stage.php"
```

Comment: Have you looked at `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Ye sand all it returns is a `bool(false) `

Comment: If it's returning false, it'll be because the path is wrong, or permissions, or some such. In which case, nothing else that you try is likely to work either.

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, you should then see a warning message that explains why it failed.

Comment: Hey i edited the qestion, could you take a look ?

Comment: The directory name `util..` doesn't look right. You need another slash before `..`.

Comment: What is `$contact`, did you mean `$content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a directory separator before `..`.

```
$stage =  __DIR__ . '/../module/stage.php';
```